# how to extract parts of string in sas

Tags: sas, sas-macro

i have multiple values in one column and i want extract some part of it.Lets consider in my column A

```
A                        B
wwwgooglecom             google
wwwyoutubecom            youtube
wwwwwwwebcom             wwwweb
wwwmywebsiteisgoodcom    websiteisgood
www.fxr.com              fxr
```

i want to extract www and com from above column A.To achieve this which sas function should i use? B column shows expected output.I tried using substr function.

```
a1 = substr(A,3,1);
a2 = substr(A,3,-1);
b  = cat(a1,a2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the SAS PRX* family of functions that perform Perl regular expression matching and replacement.

This example uses `PRXCHANGE` that searches for:

- starting `www`, followed by
- zero or one periods `\.?`, followed by
- a group that is a non-greedy match of anything `(.*?)`, up to
- an ending zero or one periods `\.?`, followed by
- an ending `com`

The captured group, `$1`, is used as the replacement.

```
data whatsup;
length a b $80;
input A& B&;

c = prxchange('s/^www\.?(.*?)\.?com$/$1/', 1, trim(a));

put / a= / b=/ c=;

datalines;
wwwgooglecom             google
wwwyoutubecom            youtube
wwwwwwwebcom             wwwweb
wwwmywebsiteisgoodcom    websiteisgood(bad sample data?)
www.fxr.com              fxr
run;
```

There are alternatives that would use `PRXMATCH`

Comment: it is worth noting that regular expression parsing in SAS is slow.  If you have a significant number of strings to parse, this is not the most efficient method.  If you have less than a few thousand, you are not going to notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `INDEX()` function and the `substr()` on the LHS of an assignment.  You can also remove the `.` with the `compress()` function:

```
data test;
format A $32.;
input A $;
datalines; 
wwwgooglecom
wwwyoutubecom
wwwwwwwebcom
wwwmywebsiteisgoodcom
www.fxr.com
;

data want;
set test;
B = compress(A,".");
if index(B,"www") then
    substr(B, index(B,"www"), 3) = "";
if index(B,"com") then
    substr(B, index(B,"com"), 3) = "";
B = strip(B);
run;
```